# updateGL() with QTimer

Tags: qt, opengl

I have a problem with updating the OpenGL model on the screen. I use the timer to update the rotation angle every timer step:

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(Spin()));
timer->start(500);

void GLWidget::Spin()
{
    qDebug() << "Spin()";

    rotationX  += 5;
    rotationY  += 5;
    rotationZ  += 5;
    updateGL();

}
```

I also tried update() instead of updateGL() but it does not work either. 
The weird thing is, by rotating the model with the mouse it does work:

```
void GLWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    GLfloat dx = GLfloat(event->x() - lastPos.x()) / width();
    GLfloat dy = GLfloat(event->y() - lastPos.y()) / height();
    if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) {
        rotationX += 180 * dy;
        rotationY += 180 * dx;
        updateGL();
    } else if (event->buttons() & Qt::RightButton) {
    rotationX += 180 * dy;
        rotationZ += 180 * dx;
        updateGL();
    }
    lastPos = event->pos();
}
```

Comment: use update() not updateGL()

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlags flags)` after the `updateGL()` call in `Spin()`, to force the draw call to be pushed through the paint queue.

I brute force approach would be to call `repaint()`, this bypasses the event queue entirely and calls `paintEvent()` immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I tried your advice and get: 'error C2275: 'QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlags' : illegal use of this type as an expression' Then I tried  `QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlags()` and there is no error message anymore, but it still does not work. What is the flags variable for and to what value should it be set?

Comment: The flags arg is a type of enum (it's Qt's own flag container to be precise), it's default initialised though - but what you have there essentially does the same thing because `QEventLoop::AllEvents` == 0x00.  Qt has very good documentation BTW: https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/classes.html.  I've edited by answer for another suggestion.